# Erlang integers in list and use them in formula's

Tags: erlang

I am learning Erlang and how to work with lists but I have a problem. I am making a program with the use of solving math problems for example `Tot = X*Y*Z.`

First I give in a variable to set the amount of problems I want to solve like this:

```
inTestes(Tests) ->AmountOfTests = Tests.
```

Now to hold my different variables I also made a record: `-record(specs,{x,y,z}).` that holds a tuplet with the 3 variables.

I try to fill this tuplet: `inSpecs(X,Y,Z)-> #specs =[x=X,y=Y,z=Z].` But this doesn't work. 
I think I need to use something like `lists:append(The variables here)->#specs{x=X,y=Y,z=Z}` but I just don't seem to get it right.
When I just do `inSpecs(X,Y,Z)-> Specs =[X,Y,Z].` I get 1 list for example `[10,20,30]`

How can I hold multiple lists like this according to the AmountOfTests?

Could someone give me some guidance?

Comment: I could be miss reading something but I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do. Would you be able to provide the current code sample and the current input/output along with the desired output?

Comment: There is a special [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp) for Erlang, OTP, Erlang VM, LFE, Elixir, and related discussions so you can ask there any question about Erlang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I try to fill this tuplet:
>
> ```
> inSpecs(X,Y,Z)-> #specs =[x=X,y=Y,z=Z].
> ```
>
> But this doesn't work

And why do you think that should work?  Do you think the following should work to create a list:

```
MyList = ! 3, 4; 5].
```

Computer programming requires *exact* syntax--not 5 out of 7 characters that are correct.

Please point to any book, website, or documentation that says that you can create a record with this syntax:

```
#specs =[x=X,y=Y,z=Z].
```

Here's what you *can* do:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).
-record(specs, {x,y,z}).

inSpecs(X,Y,Z)-> #specs{x=X,y=Y,z=Z}.
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> Record = my:inSpecs(10, 20, 30). 
{specs,10,20,30}

3> rr("my.erl").
[specs]

4> Record.
#specs{x = 10,y = 20,z = 30}

5> Record#specs.x.
10
```

> When I just do `inSpecs(X,Y,Z)-> Specs =[X,Y,Z]`. I get 1 list for
>   example `[10,20,30]`
>
> How can I hold multiple lists like this according to the
>   AmountOfTests?

Suppose `AmountOfTests` is equal to 3, what should `inSpecs/3` return?

**Response to comment**:

Here's how you can create three specs with the same data:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).
-record(specs, {x,y,z}).

inSpecs(X,Y,Z)-> #specs{x=X,y=Y,z=Z}.

create_specs(0) -> [];
create_specs(N) -> [inSpecs(1,2,3) | create_specs(N-1)].
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> rr(my).
[specs]

3> Specs = my:create_specs(3).
[#specs{x = 1,y = 2,z = 3},
 #specs{x = 1,y = 2,z = 3},
 #specs{x = 1,y = 2,z = 3}]
```

Or, if you have the data for the specs in a list like this:

```
SpecData = [ [1,2,3], [12,13,14], [7,8,9] ].
```

Then you can create a function like this:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).
-record(specs, {x,y,z}).

inSpecs(X,Y,Z)-> #specs{x=X,y=Y,z=Z}.

create_specs([]) -> [];
create_specs([ [X,Y,Z] | Tail]) -> 
    [inSpecs(X,Y,Z) | create_specs(Tail)].
```

In the shell:

```
17> f().
ok

18> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

19> SpecData = [ [1,2,3], [12,13,14], [7,8,9] ].
[[1,2,3],[12,13,14],[7,8,9]]

20> Specs = my:create_specs(SpecData).          
[#specs{x = 1,y = 2,z = 3},
 #specs{x = 12,y = 13,z = 14},
 #specs{x = 7,y = 8,z = 9}]
```

Comment: I can see what I did wrong trying to put the X,Y,Z into a record, I used the wrong syntax by being to focused on creating lists. 
The way I learned in school is that I call inSpecs in my shell and give in the 3 variables X,Y,Z. like you explaned. 
But that way I create 1 record with these value's and if I want 3 of these records I will overwrite the same record every time I call inSpecs ? 
So I would like that when AmountOfTest = 3 can build a list of 3 records so I can use the variables in this list of records to do the calculations. Perhaps I am looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: @DriesVandenberk: Once again, you are leaving out important details.  Are the three records supposed to have random values?  Or, are the three records all supposed to have the same values?  Or, something else?  Every time you call inSpecs it returns a record--you are not overwriting anything.  What you do with that record is up to you, but it is impossible to overwrite a variable because variables are single assignment.   See the additional code at the bottom of my example.

Comment: Oke I can see the confusion, sorry if I am being unclear.
The amount of records depend on inTests, so if inTests = 3 I need to call inSpecs 3 times in the shell to make 3 records. Each record holds its own value's of X,Y,Z so that I am able to solve an exercise for example Outcome=X+Y*Z   3 times with the value's in these 3 records.

Comment: *The amount of records depend on inTests, so if inTests = 3 I need to call inSpecs 3 times in the shell to make 3 records. Each record holds its own value's of X,Y,Z*--If you want each record to have its own values, then the value returned by `inTests()` is irrelevant.  As in my second example, the number of elements in the list that you pass to create_specs() will determine how many specs that are created--not the value returned by inTests().

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're trying to get the 3 values from your list and put them in your record. You can do that with pattern matching. If you know the list you are being sent has exactly 3 values in it, you can do it with the following:

```
inTests( [X, Y, Z] ) ->
    #specs{ x = X, y = Y, z = Z}.
```